# Ember JS: observe changes in an object's descendants

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have an object "watcher" that references another object: "dad". "Watcher" should be notified every time something changes in "dad".

It works when dad's children are altered, but not when dad's grand children are altered. I can't get the observer to trigger in the latter case. I guess nesting the @each is probably wrong, but I am not sure how to do this.

Is there a way to simply send a generic notification to watcher when something in dad or his descendants is modified?

```
App.Dad = DS.Model.extend({
    sons: DS.hasMany('App.Son'),
    name: null
})

App.Son = DS.Model.extend({
    dad: DS.belongsTo('App.Dad'),
    sons: DS.hasMany('App.GrandSon'),
    name: null
})

App.GrandSon = DS.Model.extend({
    dad: DS.belongsTo('App.Son'),
    name: null
})

App.Watcher = Ember.Object.extend({
    dad: null, // will be set later
    dadChanged: function(){
        // Fires if a son is changed, but not
        // if a grand son is changed
    }.observes('dad.sons.@each.name','dad.sons.@each.sons.@each.name')
})
```

Cf a jsFiddle illustrating this: http://jsfiddle.net/4kUzr/1/

Answer (score 0):

You did not outline your usecase in detail, but from an object modeling perspective i suspect to work it this way:

```
App.Person = DS.Model.extend({
    dad: DS.belongsTo('App.Person'),
    sons: DS.hasMany('App.Person'),
    name: null,
    nameObserver : function(){
       var dad = this.get("dad");
       // do some logic
       // hand it afterwards to the dad of this person
       if(dad)
         dad.nameObserver()
    }.observes("name")
});
```

So just **1 Class instead of multiple Classes and i established a parent-child relationship**.

Comment: Thanks mavilein. The example I wrote was just a very simple and stripped down one that - as you pointed out - does not reflect my use case (which is specific). Descendants might actually be of totally different types. The generic question would be: is there a simple way to notify all the ancestors when a descendant changes (i.e. traversing "up" the associations)? I am not sure your solution will work in the generic case...